# Subset a dataframe if its date is larger than a date of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as follows:

```
C1
Date|Artist
01-11-1955|M
18-01-1956|M
19-04-1956|M
01-05-1956|M
21-11-1956|X


T1
Date|Artist|FeatArtist
06-11-1955|UNK|M
15-01-1956|M|UNK
15-04-1956|UNK|M
06-05-1956|UNK|M
25-11-1956|X|UNK
25-11-1956|M|UNK
```

I want to be able to subset T1 if the T1$Artist == C1$Artist| T1$FeatArtist == C1$Artist and T1 date happened after C1 Date

The result should be:

```
T1
Date|Artist|FeatArtist
06-11-1955|UNK|M
06-05-1956|UNK|M
25-11-1956|X|UNK
```

I tried:

```
t<- T1[which(T1$Artist%in% unique(C1$Artist) | T1$FeatArtist%in% unique(C1$Artist)& T1$Date > max(C1$Date)),]
```

but didn't work out - any idea how I can achieve this please?

Comment: Why don't you take the second column of T1 yet it satisfies the conditions you gave?

Comment: How does it satisfy my conditions?

Comment: The date for the second row of T1 `04-12-1955` is less than the date for the second row of C1 `15-01-1956` while the two have the same Artist

Comment: You are so right...I have fixed the sample data...sorry

Comment: still the output does not follow the logic. For example, the second row in T1 is less than the fourth rowin C1 and both contain M as the artist...

Comment: T1 date should happen after C1 Date. I am trying to find those dates which happened in the same week considering Sunday as day 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T1$Date=as.Date(strptime(T1$Date,"%d-%m-%Y"))
C1$Date=as.Date(strptime(C1$Date,"%d-%m-%Y"))

e=quote(Date.x>Date.y&Date.x-Date.y<7)
a=subset(merge(T1,C1,by="Artist",all=TRUE),eval(e))
b=subset(merge(T1,C1,by.x="FeatArtist",by.y="Artist",all=TRUE),eval(e))
rbind(a,setNames(b,names(a)),row.names=NULL)[-4]

    Artist     Date.x FeatArtist
12       X 1956-11-25        UNK
1        M 1955-11-06        UNK
121      M 1956-05-06        UNK
```